# Can the president challenge the Supreme Court ruling so that it doesn't have to roll back actions that are deemed invalid until the next president?

Tags: united-states, government, supreme-court

Can the president challenge the Supreme Court ruling so that it doesn't have to roll back actions that are deemed invalid until the next president? Because of a legal technicality called the unitary executive the Supreme Court may call the actions taken after the 2008 financial crisis invalid and must be rolled back. Does the president have the power to slow down the legal process so that the problem goes to the next administration instead of his?

> The 2010 law creating the CFPB transferred considerable authority to
> that new agency. Among other things, CFPB enforces statutes
> prohibiting abusive debt collection practices, requiring lenders to be
> truthful with borrowers, and governing consumers’ credit reports. All
> of the CFPB’s actions to enforce these statutes could potentially be
> invalidated if the plaintiffs prevail in Collins. Indeed, if the
> Supreme Court were to embrace this position, the Biden administration
> could spend much of its first year dealing with the fact that years’
> worth of government actions are suddenly invalid and must be rolled
> back.

https://www.vox.com/22106497/supreme-court-collins-mnuchin-124-billion-fannie-mae-freddie-mac-unitary-executive-housing